# Connecting Glue Pyspark to oracle using SSL certificate

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ssl-certificate, aws-glue, oracle-wallet

I am using Spark readwrite operations for reading/writing to oracle database
Below is the code snippet:

```
empDF = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", url) \
.option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
.option("ssl", True) \
.option("sslmode", "require" ) \
.option("dbtable", query) \
.option("user", "******") \
.option("password", "******") \
.load()
```

But I **need to add oracle ssl certificate** for connecting to the data base.I tried using wallet which I added to /tmp location along with the tnsnames.ora file. I have added in the URL in the below format.

```
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@apm_url?TNS_ADMIN=/tmp"
```

**But still am getting the below error and not able to connect**

An error occurred while calling o104.load. IO Error: IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, connect lapse 30 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of the Oracle JDBC driver that you are using? Check out [QuickStart guide](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/getting-started-using-jdbc.html) for using Oracle wallets. You need to have oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar, and osdt_cert.jar in the classpath.